# Rails ActiveStorage: how to get Variant url when in proxy mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In /config/application.rb I have `config.active_storage.resolve_model_to_route = :rails_storage_proxy`.

I'm then generating the url with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(img, only_path: true)`

But I'm still getting the images served through a redirect instead of directly from my rails app like I would expect when I configured proxy mode.

Should I use a different way of generating the url? Or did i configure proxy mode wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the variant URL when in proxy mode, you need to use the method `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_storage_proxy_url(img, only_path: true)`

Aditionally, when using api only mode, you need to enable the Flash middleware by adding `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash` to your application.rb. This is necessary because of [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32208)