# Change host of ActiveStorage GCS redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm using this ActiveStorage method:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_storage_proxy_url(object, host: ENV.fetch('BLOB_HOST'))
```

My bucket is public on GCS.

Most importantly, it has a CNAME from cdn.example.com, and for the redirect URL I want it to be `cdn.example.com` and not `https://storage.googleapis.com/cdn.example.com/aaf3h8a73hfa33a9`

I cannot find any information on how to do this. The closest I've see is this:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#putting-a-cdn-in-front-of-active-storage

But this uses the proxy method.

Comment: [This](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-cdn-for-google-cloud-storage/) might help

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have the bucket name set properly with the CNAME, the problem is the rails redirect does a 302 to the bucket path and I cant override the host

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69492336/3784008